# В чем разница между словами Родина и Отечество?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, словообразование, семантика

Предлагаю разделить понятия Родины и Отечества, которые синонимичны и часто их используют как взаимозаменяемые, однако они не эквивалентны.

Comment: Ответы, пожалуйста, давайте в ответах.

Answer (score 2):

Как всякий малыш, наряду с цельным образом семьи, имеет представление о женских и мужских её началах, так и повзрослевший человек, осознающий себя частицей общества и видящий в своей стране те же родительские черты, воспринимает понятия Родина (Родительство) и Отечество (Отчизна) сторонами одной медали, неделимо связанными.

Осознание своей роли в роду определяется семейным воспитанием («*У Катерины было не умозрительное представление о долге, а родовое, от прадедов досталось*». Ю. Давыдов); для него важна непрерываемость рода, где родина — точка его происхождения. Слóва Родина нет в церковно-славянском языке, а вот Отчизна (достояние, наследство) и Отечество (род, поколение и пр.) имеют отдельные статьи как представители слов высоких. Было бы полезно внести ещё одно — Соотечественник, слово уместное в толковании достоинства этих понятий.

Comment: хорошо, я не уверен что роль и долг это синонимичные понятия(точнее совсем не согласен), но продолжайте развивать мысль. Также не согласен, что Отчизна произошло от Отчества, и еще есть же Отечество. Каким боком Отчизна превратилась в страну. Но хорошо, Отечество связано с Отец, а Родина с Мать.

Comment: Отчество здесь не обсуждалось. Отечество и Отчизна — одного значения слова. Из словаря: **Ро́дина — место рождения человека, его происхождения; родная страна, Отечество; страна, в которой человек родился и гражданином которой является**

Comment: место рождения - это родина, а не Родина. Родная мать это отец - ну бредово звучит, не так разве?

Comment: Зачем воспрозводите то, что заведомо не считаете разумным? Не стоит нарушать порядок слов, т. к. смысл меняется: не всё, что называют местом рождения, является родиной. Иногда роды случаются и не на Земле.

Comment: не придал этому принципиального значения, так как это референс на ваше утверждение, так что не стоит вырывать из контекста. Но если вам режет глаз, то можете развернуть задом наперед и добавить что не хватать, все равно вряд ли получится Родина.

Comment: Я не утверждал, что «родная мать это отец». Строчки, выделенные жирным, тоже не моё творчество, они взяты из словаря. Читайте написанное вдумчиво, без эмоций.

Comment: Ну я так понял, что Родина - это страна или место, где родился, значит Родина - это страна и Отечество - это тоже страна, получилось что мать это отец. Я многое додумал, есть такое, однако эти точки запятые и "что такое страна" не вносят ясности. Раз вы привели строчки, значит что-то в них увидели и так оставили, вот я и спрашиваю, что не понятно.

Comment: Знающих, ощущающих нутром или думающих, что понимают, что есть Отечество-Отчизна, не так много. Их познания основаны на собственном опыте. Они — сознательная часть **народа**, соль Родины, её гражданское воинство, и понятие Отечество в их жизни трудно оценить во всей его глубине. Это страна. Но это и целый мир. О Москве сказанное (*как много в этом звуке*) и к Отечеству в полной мере относится. И ещё: семьи бывают неполными, *в этом звуке* не все находят верное отражение своего чувства страны и народа. Есть проще — на каждый день.

Comment: то есть вы не в состоянии доходчиво сформулировать, что есть что? Где можно найти такого "ИХ", способных формулировать и облекать свои высокие чувства в слова? И вообще, зачем понятия, которые почти никто не понимает?

Comment: Мне кажется вы все больше запутываете, тут и религия уже,  и долг, и самоидентификация в социуме, и "осознание своей роли в роду определяется семейным воспитанием", я понимаю, что этот ряд означающих можно бесконечно продолжать и дальше, но можно попроще для простых людей?

Comment: Вы «попроще» вынули из рукава. Исправлять вопрос, чтобы сразу понимать *с кем и как*, поздно.

Comment: Да, это вы вроде писали, что простым людям этого не понять (хотя данная терминология направлена как раз на простых людей, все непростые или космополиты, или имеют другое гражданство, или еще что), но я не хочу на вас давить, просто выражаю некоторые сомнения, которые как вы понимаете имеет место быть и у вас, поддерживаю ваши сомнения, так сказать)